# Linq to Sql How to get table data

Tags: linq-to-sql

Heyah im new to Linq to Sql, how to get table value is that possible? for example i have a table name "Aquarium" inside the "Aquarium" Table i have these following "FishType" and "FishColor" then the FishColor contains "Blue" "Red"
then i have two Textboxes

TextBox1 is for "FishType" 
TextBox2 is for "FishColor"

if i type Blue in TextBox2 i want all the colored blue fish will show up.

it would be a much of help if someone show me the code lol im really new into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First go for this tutorial of how to get dbml class

http://www.progtalk.com/viewarticle.aspx?articleid=68

then follow the Source code of this tutorial with video

http://www.sexyselect.net/blog/post/2011/06/15/part1-beginners-guid-to-linq-to-sql

Comment: if it is helpful then plz mark it as answer by clicking on the arrow just below the up, down button at the left